# When thumbnail is selected style it

Tags: html, css

I have a page where there are video thumbnails (images) and when clicked on them the video plays in a bigger div. I have them styled on hover over and so on but when the video is playing I would like the current thumbnail to be styled so they know which thumbnail is playing.

I have tried adding an active class to the thumbnail div but the style of the class applies to all of them. Can anyone figure how to achieve this or where i am going wrong please?

**html code**

```
<div class="main">
<iframe width="800" height="500" src="video-1.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<ul>
<li class="thumbnail"><a href="video-1.mp4" class="video-1" title=""><img src="images/videoPlayer-thumbnail-1.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
<li class="thumbnail"><a href="video-2.mp4" class="video-2" title=""><img src="images/videoPlayer-thumbnail-2.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
<li class="thumbnail"><a href="video-3.mp4" class="video-3" title=""><img src="images/videoPlayer-thumbnail-3.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: try somthing like .thumbnail:active{}

Comment: yep- tried that and nothing - thanks though, it must be the page refreshing as each video has a id, so annoying!

Comment: my bad you can use .thumbnail a:active{}

Comment: Yeah tried that as well and when clicked the styling shows but then after i have clicked it, the styling is removed. Not sure if a little JQuery is needed!

Comment: if you want it too bad then jquery is the best option. coz it wont create problem related to browser compatibilities and all that.

Comment: I think its with the deeplinking i will need to change my a tags to divs so the page is not refreshed, will let you know how i get on

Answer (score 0):

If page not refresh, you can add a CLASS to the clicked IMG, and then you can change whatever way you want your style

EDIT:

```
<li class="thumbnail">
  <a href="video-3.mp4?class=link1" class="video-3" title="">
     <img src="images/videoPlayer-thumbnail-3.jpg" alt=""/>
  </a>
</li>
```

And using jQuery split the URL and find the parameter, then match the css path.

Comment: Ive followed your advice and no luck, the page must be refreshing as i have a script that each video has a deep link attached to it. Hope this makes sense?